# numpy.dot - ensuring matrix compatibility?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I've got a 2D array `X`.

`X[i]` is a 1D array with 3 values.
Its shape is: `(3L,)`

I then have a 3D array, `g`, which is 2x3x2.
If I print out the shape of `g[j]`, it is: `(3L,2L)` and the shape of `g[j][i]` is `(2L,)`

Now I'm running a loop like this:

```
for j in range(len(g)):
            for i in range(no_samples):
            e = math.exp(1. + np.dot(X[i], g[j][i]) - np.dot(X[i],g[i_class][i]))
```

But I get the following error:

```
  e = math.exp(1. + np.dot(X[i], g[j][i]) - np.dot(X[i],g[i_class][i]))
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

I guess I understand the problem, but don't know how to fix it. I tried transposing `g[j][i]` but it didn't make a difference. I tried reshaping `X[i]` to force it to be `(3L,1L)`. I thought that if `X[i]` is 3x1 and `g[j][i]` is 1x2, then the matrices are compatible and I should be able to use `np.dot`. But I think I must be missing something.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your assumption that the shapes are 3x1 and 1x2 is faulty. You would need to forcibly reshape both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is that both arrays are only 1D and of unequal size. There is two solutions to this problem:

Lets start with this:

```
>>> x
array([3, 4, 5])
>>> x.shape
(3,)             #Same shape as your array, but note that it is only 1D
>>> g
array([2, 3])
```

Way 1- Reshape:

```
>>> np.dot(x.reshape(3,1), g.reshape(1,2))
array([[ 6,  9],
       [ 8, 12],
       [10, 15]])
```

Way 2- `np.outer`:

```
>>> np.outer(x,g)
array([[ 6,  9],
       [ 8, 12],
       [10, 15]])
```

When accessing numpy arrays instead of `g[i_class][i]` use `g[i_class,i]`. Also, the transpose of a 1D array does not change the array.

Finally, if you run your script as shown with this you will get an additional error. `math.exp` does not take numpy arrays as an input. To circumvent this you either need to use `np.exp` or sum elements together to return a single scalar.